# Why is the string split into characters in python

Tags: python

The following is the code I wrote:

```py
def comb(self, rows, cols):
    return [s+t for s in a for t in b]
```

If the values of `rows` and `cols` are

```py
rows = ['abc','efg']
cols = ['123','456']
```

Expected output: `['abc123','abc456,'efg123','efg456']`

Program output: `['a1', 'a2', 'a3', 'b1', 'b2', 'b3', 'c1', 'c2', 'c3']`

I am new to Python programming. Could you help me understand what is happening? I already fixed the output but I would like to understand why this happened.

Comment: could you show us some more code? The function takes parameters `rows` and `cols` and you are iterating through `a` and `b`

Comment: That code does not give that output

Comment: It was an error in my code because instead of taking the string as it is I was using each string as an input for the comb function

def comb(self, rows, cols): return [s+t for s in a for t in b]

rows = ['abc','efg'] cols = ['123','456']

print [comb(rs, cs) for rs in rows for cs in cols]

so the output was ['a1', 'a2', 'a3', 'b1', 'b2', 'b3', 'c1', 'c2', 'c3']

in this function, it would take each character of the string and the output will be a combination of the characters instead of the string.

But thank you for trying to help. I really appreciate it.

Comment: I have posted the solution and the issue in this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/67064847/5016391

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To understand what your list comprehension is doing, you can rewrite it like this:

```
results = []
for s in a:
    for t in b:
        results.append(s+t)
```

Presumably that's not what you want.

Comment: That is a good explanation of what is going wrong in OP's question, but it doesn't give a solution to it.

Comment: This is a good answer, but a bit terse. Maybe say a few words  in English about what python is doing, to help out the new head?

Comment: @JacobLee The original question was "Could you help me understand what is happening?" This is a good start at that :)

Comment: @JacobLee OP is not asking for a solution. _ I already fixed the output but I would like to understand why this happened._

Comment: Would def comb(self, *rows, *cols): work ?

Comment: @NicholasHunter the code you suggested works well

Comment: Thanks for the solutions and explanations. im really new to this community

Comment: Happy to help :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `zip()` function:

```py
>>> rows = ['abc','efg']
>>> cols = ['123','456']
>>> def comb(rows, cols):
    return [r+c for r, c in zip(rows, cols)]

>>> comb(rows, cols)
['abc123', 'efg456']
```

The `zip()` function, in essence, pairs each value in `rows` with each value in `cols`.

```py
>>> list(zip(rows, cols))
[('abc', '123'), ('efg', '456')]
```

On the other hand, `[s+t for s in a for t in b]` is a nested `for` loop, with iterations of `a` nested in iterations of `b`.

Answer (score 0):

change it to this:

```
rows = ['abc','efg']
cols = ['123','456']

def comb(rows, cols):
    return [s+t for s in rows for t in cols]

print(comb(rows,cols))
```

output:

```
['abc123', 'abc456', 'efg123', 'efg456']
```

Comment: OP was asking for an explanation, not a fix.

Comment: yup just realized that

Answer (score 0):

The `itertools` library is a popular Python standard library containing many tools that help you iterate over different ways of combining itrators (such as your given `rows` and `cols` lists).

```
import itertools

def comb(rows, cols):
    return map(lambda t: t[0] + t[1], itertools.product(rows, cols))
```

`itertools.product` will give you an iterator full of tuples which give you all the possible combinations of the entries in `rows` as the first element, and the entries in `cols` as the second element.

`map` uses the `lambda` function given to join the two strings in the tuple produced by `itertools.product` into one string, which is what you want.

To get the list that you mentioned you want, you can wrap the call to `map` in the function `list()` to evaluate the `map`-produced iterator into a list. Fyi, for large lists, this will be inefficient, as the result of combining the substrings will all live in memory, whereas if you use the iterator provided by the first `def comb` I gave you, when you iterate over those iterators, you'll use rules to generate each entry as you go.

Answer (score 0):

It was an error in my code because instead of taking the string as it is I was using each string as an input for the comb function

def comb(self, rows, cols):
return [s+t for s in a for t in b]

rows = ['abc','efg']
cols = ['123','456']

print [comb(rs, cs) for rs in rows for cs in cols]

so the output was ['a1', 'a2', 'a3', 'b1', 'b2', 'b3', 'c1', 'c2', 'c3']

in this function, it would take each character of the string and the output will be a combination of the characters instead of the string.

But thank you for trying to help. I really appreciate it.